# Change SWT TreeItem parent

Tags: java, user-interface, tree, widget, swt

I am making a program in Java and I have a SWT tree widget that the user is supposed to toy with via drag and drop.

Now the problem is that when the user drags and drops a branch, I want to change the branch item's parent to whichever treeItem it was dropped on, but there doesn't appear to be any way to do so. I could simply create a new treeItem, but there is no easy way to transfer the children, so I need to redefine all the children, and their grandchildren and so on recursively. It seems pretty klunky and inefficient to me that I need to remake the entire branch just to change the parent.

Is there any clean way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the clean way is to separate view/widgets from model (as in MVC). In case of SWT, you should use [`TreeViewer`](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/viewers/TreeViewer.html) and implement [`ITreeContentProvider`](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/viewers/ITreeContentProvider.html). jFace will take care of creating tree nodes for you and you only need to update your model and refresh the viewer.